how to color specific rows of a table in fastreport
i have a table month I marked the weekend days with other colors in DBGrid (OnDrawcolumnCell)
if (ADOQ1days.Value = 'Friyday') OR (ADOQ1days.Value = 'Saturday') then
begin
  DBGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $0053FFFF ;
  DBGrid2.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field,State);
end;

i want to keep this color when printing the report


I don't use FastReport myself, but you may want to look at their blog, e.g. https://www.fast-report.com/blogs/style-vcl-report

@Tom Brunberg  I didn't find what I was looking for

Why not? There's an example of doing exactly what you're asking for (coloring lines of the report in different shades).

@Ken White  ah? i will review it carefully

@Ken White  the example in the blog color line by line
my case is to color only saturday and friday like in the DBGrid, please see the image  i have added an image

What you are looking for is Conditional highlighting
You might also learn more about conditional highlighting from How to use Conditional Highlighting and Sums with FastReport video.

this is exactly what i am looking for thank you very much.
